# Angular directive doesnt seem to be executing with the passed in options from the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Ive got a simple example hosted on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nixgadget/paad9w41/) which includes an angular directive `angularbfi` to wrap the `bootstrap-forminput` by https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput.

The code for the relevant directive is,

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('angularBootstrapFileinput', [])
    .directive('angularBfi', angularBootstrapFileinput);

function angularBootstrapFileinput() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            options: '=angularBfi',
            watchOptions: '@?watchOptions'
        },
        link: linkFunc,
        controller: AngularBootstrapFileinputController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;

    function linkFunc(scope, element) {
        element.fileinput(scope.vm.options);
        scope.vm.refresh = refresh;
        activate();

        function activate() {
            if (scope.vm.watchOptions){
                scope.$watch('vm.options', refresh, true);
            }
        }
        function refresh() {
            element.fileinput('refresh', scope.vm.options);
        }
    }
}

function AngularBootstrapFileinputController(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.watchOptions = angular.isDefined(vm.watchOptions) && vm.watchOptions === "true";
}
})();
```

I cant seem to pass the `{'showUpload':false, 'showPreview':false}` to this. What am i possibly doing wrong here ?

Code attached.
https://jsfiddle.net/nixgadget/paad9w41/

Comment: Did you include it in your app dependencies?

Comment: I mean to say did you inject it into your app's dependencies during initialisation?

Comment: Not sure i understand. You mean to say ``angular.module('app', ['angularBootstrapFileinput']);``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that it wasnt loading due to directive being camel-cased `angularBfi` the input attribute has to be `angular-bfi`

Hence,

```
<input type="file" class="file" name="upload" data-show-preview="false"  data-show-upload="false" />
```

I have also updated https://jsfiddle.net/nixgadget/paad9w41/2/